# swift : Enum constant with type and value

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums, swift, ios8

I know, enumeration constant should be like this in swift

```
enum CompassPoint {
    case North
    case South
    case East
    case West
}
```

But how can I assign value to first element, like Objective-C code as below

```
enum ShareButtonID : NSInteger
{
   ShareButtonIDFB = 100,
   ShareButtonIDTwitter,
   ShareButtonIDGoogleplus

}ShareButtonID;
```

Comment: Just read this [official documentation and (search Enumerations and Structures).](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/GuidedTour.html) Hope that might be solve your confusion.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You need to give the enum a type and then set values, in the example below `North` is set as `100`, the rest will be `101`, `102` etc, just like in `C` and `Objective-C`.

```
enum CompassPoint: Int {
    case North = 100, South, East, West
}

let rawNorth = CompassPoint.North.rawValue // => 100
let rawSouth = CompassPoint.South.rawValue // => 101
// etc.
```

**Update**: Replace `toRaw()` with `rawValue`.

Comment: `toRaw()` has been replaced with `rawValue`

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, nacho4d. I have updated the answer with a short comment about the change.

Comment: @fnc12: There is not Swift 2.3…

Answer (score -2):

```
struct AppConstant {
//Usage: AppConstant.IntValues.fifteen.rawValue
enum IntValues: Int {
    case zero = 0
    case one = 1
    case two = 2
    case three = 3
    case four = 4
    case five = 5
    case six = 6
    case seven = 7
    case eight = 8
    case nine = 9
    case ten = 10
    case eleven = 11
    case twelve = 12
    case thirteen = 13
    case fourteen = 14
    case fifteen = 15
    
    func asCGFloat() -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(self.rawValue)
    }
    
    func asFloat() -> Float {
        return Float(self.rawValue)
    }
    
    func asDouble() -> Double {
        return Double(self.rawValue)
    }
    
    func asString() -> String {
        return "\(self.rawValue)"
    }
   }
}
```